Resource type in google cloud logs falls back to 'global' when logged from dataproc using google-cloud-logging python library
I have a python code which runs in the context of GCP DataProc. The project uses google-cloud-logging python library for logging (as far as I understand it is formerly known as 'Stackdriver' logs).
I noticed that the logs in GCP logs explorer console have "default" type 'global', while I would expect them to be of 'cloud_dataproc_job' type.
I dug into 'google-cloud-logging' code and found that it indeed doesn't infere DataProc context:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/blob/main/google/cloud/logging_v2/client.py#L379-L390
https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/blob/main/google/cloud/logging_v2/handlers/_monitored_resources.py#L201-L235
So, I have a few questions: is my understanding correct and DataProc is indeed not supported? If so, what would be a good workaround to associate the DataProc type and the correct DataProc job_id to the logs? It will help to trace and investigate the jobs issues.
